# Как сделать архив из множества файлов? C#

Tags: c#, .net, archive

Здравствуйте. Я хочу узнать, как можно заархивировать множество файлов, но я имею ввиду не .zip и прочее, ведь мне нужно будет этот архив зашифровать. Существуют какие-либо библиотеки? Примером могут служить архивы игровых файлов у движков, в которых содержаться звуки, текстуры и прочее.

Comment: zip с паролем используйте

Comment: @АндрейNOP попробую, спасибо

Comment: А почему .zip-то не подходит? Его тоже можете зашифровать. Любую последовательность бит можно зашифровать)